# Table Sorting, Filtering, Etc Matt Kruse's library

Tags: javascript, html, filter, filtering

### Situation:

I'm playing a little by using the Matt Kruse's library I found at the page **Table Sorting, Filtering, Etc** at the URL http://javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/source.php.

It works pretty well but I wish to implement a little improvement (maybe it would be better to use the locution "new feature") and I don't know where to start because I'm a newbie in js and that js file uses more advanced programming statements I don't fully understand, not yet at least.

I have a single html file with some tables in it. Some of them are filterable and sortable thanks to that library. The number of tables may vary, the number of columns (fields) in each table may vary as well, and the number of records (rows) of each table may vary as well too. Of course the content is different in each table too.

By placing a specific css class in the th element of the targeted column I choose, I indicate to the Matt Kruse's library to create in that column a  html element that is populated of a list of  html elements that are computed dynamically by the js it self by picking a distinct and sole value of each record for that column.

When I wish to apply a filter to the table on the basis of certain column, I have just to choose the relative  from the corresponding  box and the table gets filtered accordingly, as I expect to. It works just hiding the records (the html rows) with not matching criteria in that specific column with a filter applied on it. Of course it is possible to use filters on more than one column at once if needed. It works pretty similarly to MS Excel.

### The problem

When I apply a filter to a column the other columns filter drop-down combo boxes (the  html elements that contain the compiled options for filtering other columns) continue to show all options instead of hiding those that are filtered in the table and are no more needed. So it becomes pretty tricky especially on complex tables to choose filtering criteria from other columns because the user has to understand by himself what are the criteria that aren't usable because the corresponding rows are already hidden by a filter already applied to another column.

One more thing: when I edit the content of one or more table cells, the filter of the relative column(s) doesn't update to match the editing made, but it seems to be to stay static.

### Goal of this question

If I use a spreadsheet (as LibreOffice Calc, or MS Excel, or Google online spreadsheet, or else) when I filter a column other columns' filter drop down menu are filtered as well. If I remove a filter somewhere, other columns filters drop down are updated accordingly.

All this behavior is what I would like to implement into Matt Kruse's library. In this way it would be easier to filter by multiple columns because the  boxes containing the filter criteria of the other columns will show just the filter criteria left by the all the previously applied filters.

### What I have already tried

I tried to implement something to do that but it was so slow that I was too much ashamed of its execution time that I already deleted the whole algorithm I created.
For comparison using the Matt Kruse's library algorithm implies just few instants to compile all tables data into filter  elements (on all tables as well). But the algorithm I've implemented needed more than 30-40 seconds for just one table. Way too inefficient.
Substantially I wrote few "for loops" that for each  into each  of the filtered table, compares the value of the option with each one of the corresponding column and if finds a mach keeps the option visible, else it hides that  element into the . I attached that algorithm to the **change event** of each , so when I clicked and selected the  the event was triggered and all the  content of the table was updated. It worked as expected but, as I said, what I implemented was way slower.

### So the question is:

How do I modify the Matt Kruse's js file to implement the feature I want keeping the highest possible performance?

(If Matt Kruse is reading this, feel free to pick up this idea and implement the new features needed above: I'm sure it would be greatly appreciated).

Thanks everybody in advance for the contribution.